# Nhibernate - Referencing transient objects in disconnected sessions

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've been banging my head against a brick wall for nearly two days on this so any help would be great.

The scenario I've got is basically this.

I have an object called `Campaign` which I'm creating from scratch in a web client.  The `Campaign` has a reference to another object, `Portal`.  The `Portal` has been pulled from the database through NHibernate.

When I come to call `CreateCampaign(Campaign cmp)` NH barfs saying that the reference to `Portal` is transient and must be saved first.  If i create EVERYTHING from scratch then it works fine.

So in short I have a new `Campaign` instance which references a detached instance of `Portal`.  The cascades are set to 'save-update, merge'.

Do I need to reload all of the detached instances back into the session before I can call session.Save or is it something else I'm not aware of.

Sorry if this seems a little vague and for the lack of any code,..NDAs stop me from posting and code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ISession.Lock` to attach your transient object to the same session that is being used to persist Campaign:

```
session.Lock(myPortal, LockMode.None);
myCampaign.Portal = myPortal;
session.Save(myCampaign);
```

Comment: doesn't this mean I've got to reconstruct the campaign though?  I've got lots of detached instances further down the model so doing this would make most operations very involved.  I was hoping that i could just pass the new campaign and let NH do the rest,..or am i asking too much?

Comment: This exchange leads me to conclude that Lock's behavior depends on your cascade settings: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=961144&view=next. I don't know if calling Lock on a persistent object (Campaign) would cascade to the child objects or if you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: I actually ended up changing the cascade settings and using session.refresh and the session.merge.  You on the right track though,.thanks.